# TinyMCE return content without HTML

Tags: javascript, tinymce, wysiwyg

I am using an inline editor [ipweditor](http://spacebug.com/projects/ipweditor_in-place_wysiwyg_editor/) tool which internally use tinyMCE editor. On their demo page it is using old version of tinyMCE which is not working in my IE. So I updated tinyMCE with latest version.

In old version of TinyMCE it was returning me defined content with all the HTML tags, while in new version it is returning me only text without HTML tags.
Here is the link of jsFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nehalpatel/ya9Vh/1/). Anyone know how do I configure tinyMCE so it return me HTML tags also.

HTML

```
<div style="display:none">
    <form method="post" action="somepage">
        <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
<div style="border: solid thin gray; padding:5px;">
    <div class="my_text"><b> <span>Click me! I am editable and WYSIWYG!!!</span></b> 
</div>
```

Javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var ed = new tinymce.Editor('content', {
        mode: "exact",
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "emotions,table",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,fontselect,fontsizeselect,forecolor,backcolor,|,code,",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
        table_default_cellspacing: 0,
        table_default_border: 1,
        remove_linebreaks: false
    });

    $('.my_text').editable({
        type: 'wysiwyg',
        editor: ed,
        onSubmit: function submitData(content) {
            alert(content.current);
        },
        submit: 'save',
        cancel: 'cancel'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's always not preferable to make any modification in plugin library, but this really need some modification. The problem was with 'ipweditor.js' tool. It's creating new tinyMCE editor object internally and getting response in "text" format from tinyMCE.

```
var r =options.editor.getContent({format : 'text'});
```

We need to replace 'text' with 'html'

```
var r =options.editor.getContent({format : 'html'});
```

It's more preferable to make this format setting also dynamic so append a setting variable in inital settings and fetch value from there.

```
var defaults = {
    onEdit: null,
    onSubmit: null,
    onCancel: null,
    editClass: null,
    submit: null,
    cancel: null,
    type: 'text', //text, textarea or select
    submitBy: 'blur', //blur,change,dblclick,click
    editBy: 'click',
    editor: 'non',
    options: null,
    format:'text'
}
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

and now retrieve using the format defined in setting.

```
var r =options.editor.getContent({format : options.format});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `content.previous`. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6tTBj/) is a modified fiddle.

Comment: indeed 'content.pervious' shows the text with HTML tags, but I want edited text 'content.current' with all HTML tags.

Comment: looks like ipweditor does not support this (or needs to be configured especially - check the docs). An other approach to solve this could be to use the tinymce editor commands before submit(the editor object is gone when the ipweditor submit gets called!).

Comment: @Tharima : Yes the problem was with ipweditor. It was creating internally another object of tinyMCE and getting content in "text" format, need to replace it with 'html'.