# Convert Html to plain text

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I used tinymce editor for rich text editor. My problem is when i save the text, its saves in html format like

```
<p> Hello world<p/>
```

I need a plain text i.e. "Hello World" in above example.
I search on google and I find something like html encode. I don't know what that is. I am new to this concept. I am using asp.net MVC 5 and I have used tinymce as:

Model is

```
namespace ProjectNSAS.Models{
public class AboutModels
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: try editor.getContent({format : 'text'});

see - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872569/tinymce-return-content-without-html

Comment: How and where do i use this?

Comment: Didn't realize you are using the MVC nuget package, added an answer

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best of help,, but a .txt file is also a form of plain text. If you just want to see the code and not run it, try doing something with .txt.

Answer (score 0):

HTML has some characters which mean special things to HTML. Specifically, opening and closing tags ("<" and ">"), when put together, mean that the content between them specifies an element. If you have these characters when they aren't meant for HTML tags, HTML parsers have trouble. When an HTML file wants to represent literal greater-than or less-than characters, it "encodes" them by replacing them with ">" and "<", respectively. Browsers and other HTML-consuming products know that those two strings represent "escaped" HTML characters.

.NET has a small library for escaping/unescaping HTML strings - it's the [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpUtility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. specifically, check out [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood the editor provides a getcontent method, the integration doesn't provide an access point that I can easily find. However the implementation is rather simple.

TinyMCE has the following code to convert it's html to text:

In: jquery.tinymce.js:

```
... t.getContent().replace(/<(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">])*>/g, "") ...
```

Which basically is just a javascript regex replacement, do the same in your C# code, and then decode the html.

Here is a sample controller:

```
public class TinyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TinyMCEModelJQuery model)
    {
        var foo = model.Content;
        Regex regex = new Regex("<(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>");
        var htmlPlainText = regex.Replace(foo, string.Empty);
        var plainText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(htmlPlainText);
        // do what you need with plainText

        return View();

    }
```