# Replacing all <p></p> tags in my string

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi all I am using tinymce editor where I am getting the content as follows when I submit

`<p> Hi </p>`

`<p> Hi </p>`
What I need to I would like to replace all the

tags so that it should return me a plain text

I tried this but not getting as expected so can some one help me

```
 var mystring = "<p>test</p><p>test</p>"
alert(mystring.replace(/(<p[^>]+?>|<p>|<\/p>)/, ":"));
```

Comment: why not use jQuery's `text()` method? :)

Comment: With jQuery you can strip all the tags using `$('<div>' + mystring + '</div>').text()`

Comment: The biggest question is why are you using tinymce if you don´t want rich text?

Comment: I don't have problem with using tinymce but while validating the string length it is taking the <p> tags

Comment: [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872569/tinymce-return-content-without-html)
**coting**
`var r =options.editor.getContent({format : 'text'});`
We need to replace 'text' with 'html'
`var r =options.editor.getContent({format : 'html'});`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your regex should be

```
mystring.replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, ":")
```

and if you don't want to replace them by colon then

```
mystring.replace(/<p>|<\/p>/g, "")
```

if you don't want to use jquery method as suggested by @alex and @jcubic above then

```
var mystring = "<p>test</p><p>test</p>";
mystring = mystring.split( "<p>" ).join( "" ).split( "</p>" ).join( "" );
```

to cover for case-sensitive paragraph tags

```
var mystring = "<p>test</p><p>test</p>";
mystring = mystring.split( /<\/p>|<p>/ ).join( "" );
```

and if you want to put comma between two adjacent paragraph tags then

```
var mystring = "<p>test</p><p>test</p>";
mystring = mystring.split( /<\/p><p>/ ).join( "," );
mystring = mystring.split( /<\/p>|<p>/ ).join( "" );
```

Answer (score 1):

`string.match()` can also be used to extract text:

```js
var mystring = "<p>test</p><p>test</p>";

var str = mystring.match(/([^<>//]\w+)/g);

document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```